# How can I measure the power given to a USB WiFi adapter's antenna in dBm or mW?

Tags: usb, antenna, multimeter, wifi, watts

I have an Alfa AWUS036ACH USB WiFi adapter, and would like to know how much power is being given to the antennas (in dBm or mW). The Amazon link to it is here: [https://www.amazon.com/Long-Range-Dual-Band-Wireless-External-Antennas/dp/B00VEEBOPG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VEEBOPG)

Is there some sort of tool or meter I can screw into the adapter in place of the antenna(s) that would give me a reading of the power in dBm or mW? Perhaps some sort of multimeter?

I understand how this is different from antenna gain, which is not what I'm after. I'm just wondering how to measure the Wattage coming from the little antenna ports.

Comment: See: [Signal strength in telecommunications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_strength_in_telecommunications)

Comment: You could use a wattmeter for this, or for a more frequency specific measurement some attenuators and a spectrum analyzer.  About the only thing you can likely do *inexpensively* is to see the numbers listed in the FCC test report.  What is your actual goal?

Comment: Also, since WiFi is inherently very bursty with, for humans, short bursts, and to make matters more complicated, birth uses OFDM which is far from being a constant envelope signal, and dynamically adjusts output power ("power control")  you'll have to pick a duration across which to average to get a somewhat  meaningful answer.

Comment: @Christ Stratton I've recently gotten into antennas and WiFi technology and am just curious

Comment: 1) Spell names correctly 2) Read the FCC test report.  You're not going to be able to afford the test gear on a "curiosity" budget, but you can understand the results of others measurements.

Comment: Every position change of the antenna joints, every nearby object, will have some effect, as will the band and channel selection.   A calibrated receiver and antenna, a shielded room, can do an accurate determination.